# SQL (Postgres) Optimal Number of Joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query is being performed in postgres version 12. This query poses 8 joins, and lasts approximately 5 seconds.

**Query 1**

```
select *
from "public"."products" "P"
    inner join "system"."categories" "C" on "C"."id" = "P"."id_category"
    inner join "public"."businesses" "E" on "E"."id" = "P"."id_business"
    left join "public"."product_files" "pf" on "pf"."id_product" = "P"."id"
    left join "system"."files" "f" on "f"."name" = "pf"."img_code"
    left join "public"."product_variations" "pv" on ("pv"."id_product" = "P"."id" and "pv"."status" <> 'Deleted')
    left join "public"."product_stocks" "ps" on ("ps"."id_product_variation" = "pv"."id" and "ps"."status" <> 'Deleted')
    left join "public"."product_stocks" "pps" on ("pps"."id_product" = "P"."id" and "pps"."status" <> 'Deleted')
    inner join search_products( array['tires'], 8, 1, 'es') "search" on search.id = "P"."id"
where "P"."status" <> 'Deleted'
```

**Postgres Query EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for Query 1**

```
Merge Join  (cost=112948.60..121805.61 rows=4996 width=1145) (actual time=2003.599..2426.892 rows=40 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: ("P".id = search.id)
  Buffers: shared hit=760531, temp read=16912 written=18837
  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=112888.52..120950.73 rows=287945 width=1105) (actual time=1607.013..2093.722 rows=380961 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: ("P".id = pf.id_product)
        Buffers: shared hit=752079, temp read=15561 written=15606
        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=16288.22..19167.29 rows=57631 width=771) (actual time=165.803..271.662 rows=76193 loops=1)
              Merge Cond: ("P".id = pps.id_product)
              Buffers: shared hit=3820, temp read=2706 written=2733
              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=16287.81..16577.01 rows=57631 width=686) (actual time=165.787..217.878 rows=56921 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: ("P".id = pv.id_product)
                    Buffers: shared hit=2058, temp read=2706 written=2733
                    ->  Sort  (cost=14888.93..15033.01 rows=57631 width=514) (actual time=156.825..175.154 rows=56920 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: "P".id
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 21840kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=1430, temp read=2706 written=2733
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=43.49..2484.49 rows=57631 width=514) (actual time=0.266..64.052 rows=57631 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: ("P".id_business = "E".id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=1430
                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=37.81..2322.14 rows=57631 width=374) (actual time=0.214..39.402 rows=57631 loops=1)
                                      Hash Cond: ("P".id_category = "C".id)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1427
                                      ->  Seq Scan on products "P"  (cost=0.00..2132.41 rows=57631 width=252) (actual time=0.009..12.754 rows=57631 loops=1)
                                            Filter: ((status)::text <> 'Deleted'::text)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                            Buffers: shared hit=1412
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=25.14..25.14 rows=1014 width=122) (actual time=0.201..0.201 rows=1014 loops=1)
                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 124kB
                                            Buffers: shared hit=15
                                            ->  Seq Scan on categories "C"  (cost=0.00..25.14 rows=1014 width=122) (actual time=0.007..0.078 rows=1014 loops=1)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=15
                                ->  Hash  (cost=4.19..4.19 rows=119 width=140) (actual time=0.047..0.048 rows=119 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 29kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                      ->  Seq Scan on businesses "E"  (cost=0.00..4.19 rows=119 width=140) (actual time=0.013..0.024 rows=119 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=3
                    ->  Sort  (cost=1398.88..1399.05 rows=70 width=172) (actual time=8.956..8.958 rows=3 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: pv.id_product
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 43kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=628
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=4.58..1396.73 rows=70 width=172) (actual time=8.853..8.912 rows=70 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (ps.id_product_variation = pv.id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=628
                                ->  Seq Scan on product_stocks ps  (cost=0.00..1259.35 rows=50589 width=85) (actual time=0.009..7.030 rows=50595 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ((status)::text <> 'Deleted'::text)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 73
                                      Buffers: shared hit=626
                                ->  Hash  (cost=3.70..3.70 rows=70 width=87) (actual time=0.048..0.049 rows=70 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 16kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=2
                                      ->  Seq Scan on product_variations pv  (cost=0.00..3.70 rows=70 width=87) (actual time=0.020..0.039 rows=70 loops=1)
                                            Filter: ((status)::text <> 'Deleted'::text)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 66
                                            Buffers: shared hit=2
              ->  Index Scan using product_stocks_id_product_id_product_variation_id_location_key on product_stocks pps  (cost=0.41..1819.97 rows=50589 width=85) (actual time=0.013..17.822 rows=49924 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((status)::text <> 'Deleted'::text)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                    Buffers: shared hit=1762
        ->  Materialize  (cost=96600.25..98040.03 rows=287955 width=334) (actual time=1441.203..1613.160 rows=380961 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=748259, temp read=12855 written=12873
              ->  Sort  (cost=96600.25..97320.14 rows=287955 width=334) (actual time=1441.198..1567.183 rows=284596 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: pf.id_product
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 102840kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=748259, temp read=12855 written=12873
                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.84..44546.48 rows=287955 width=334) (actual time=0.021..1013.742 rows=287955 loops=1)
                          Merge Cond: ((pf.img_code)::text = (f.name)::text)
                          Buffers: shared hit=748259
                          ->  Index Scan using product_files_pkey on product_files pf  (cost=0.42..10516.05 rows=287955 width=66) (actual time=0.005..184.173 rows=287955 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=289884
                          ->  Index Scan using files_pkey on files f  (cost=0.42..29304.42 rows=455180 width=268) (actual time=0.005..338.206 rows=455178 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=458375
  ->  Sort  (cost=60.08..62.58 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=313.554..313.558 rows=36 loops=1)
        Sort Key: search.id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        Buffers: shared hit=8452, temp read=1351 written=3231
        ->  Function Scan on search_products search  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=313.544..313.545 rows=8 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=8452, temp read=1351 written=3231
Planning Time: 2.632 ms
Execution Time: 2440.414 ms
```

I was reviewing the way to optimize the query, so I was doing the joins one by one to see where the problem was, and among so many permutations in order of join, I realized that postgres from join number 7, apparently stops find the best way to run the query. So, when i delete any (randomly) join, the query lasts 300ms

**Query 2**

```
select *
from "public"."products" "P"
    inner join "system"."categories" "C" on "C"."id" = "P"."id_category"
    left join "public"."product_files" "pf" on "pf"."id_product" = "P"."id"
    left join "system"."files" "f" on "f"."name" = "pf"."img_code"
    left join "public"."product_variations" "pv" on ("pv"."id_product" = "P"."id" and "pv"."status" <> 'Deleted')
    left join "public"."product_stocks" "ps" on ("ps"."id_product_variation" = "pv"."id" and "ps"."status" <> 'Deleted')
    left join "public"."product_stocks" "pps" on ("pps"."id_product" = "P"."id" and "pps"."status" <> 'Deleted')
    inner join search_products( array['tires'], 8, 1, 'es') "search" on search.id = "P"."id"
where "P"."status" <> 'Deleted'
```

**Postgres Query EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for Query 2**

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1365.30..6482.09 rows=4996 width=1005) (actual time=349.888..350.399 rows=40 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=9339, temp read=1351 written=3231
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1364.88..3893.89 rows=4996 width=737) (actual time=349.866..349.957 rows=40 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=9179, temp read=1351 written=3231
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1364.46..3250.90 rows=1000 width=671) (actual time=349.857..349.899 rows=8 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=9147, temp read=1351 written=3231
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1364.04..2759.11 rows=1000 width=586) (actual time=349.839..349.853 rows=8 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: ("P".id_category = "C".id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=9119, temp read=1351 written=3231
                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1326.23..2718.65 rows=1000 width=464) (actual time=349.566..349.574 rows=8 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (pv.id_product = "P".id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=9104, temp read=1351 written=3231
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=4.58..1396.73 rows=70 width=172) (actual time=8.953..9.013 rows=70 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (ps.id_product_variation = pv.id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=628
                                ->  Seq Scan on product_stocks ps  (cost=0.00..1259.35 rows=50589 width=85) (actual time=0.008..7.060 rows=50595 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ((status)::text <> 'Deleted'::text)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 73
                                      Buffers: shared hit=626
                                ->  Hash  (cost=3.70..3.70 rows=70 width=87) (actual time=0.047..0.048 rows=70 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 16kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=2
                                      ->  Seq Scan on product_variations pv  (cost=0.00..3.70 rows=70 width=87) (actual time=0.015..0.033 rows=70 loops=1)
                                            Filter: ((status)::text <> 'Deleted'::text)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 66
                                            Buffers: shared hit=2
                          ->  Hash  (cost=1309.15..1309.15 rows=1000 width=292) (actual time=340.542..340.543 rows=8 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=8476, temp read=1351 written=3231
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.54..1309.15 rows=1000 width=292) (actual time=340.505..340.535 rows=8 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=8476, temp read=1351 written=3231
                                      ->  Function Scan on search_products search  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=340.483..340.485 rows=8 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=8452, temp read=1351 written=3231
                                      ->  Index Scan using products_pkey on products "P"  (cost=0.29..1.30 rows=1 width=252) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=8)
                                            Index Cond: (id = search.id)
                                            Filter: ((status)::text <> 'Deleted'::text)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=24
                    ->  Hash  (cost=25.14..25.14 rows=1014 width=122) (actual time=0.268..0.268 rows=1014 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 124kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=15
                          ->  Seq Scan on categories "C"  (cost=0.00..25.14 rows=1014 width=122) (actual time=0.012..0.110 rows=1014 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=15
              ->  Index Scan using product_stocks_id_product_id_product_variation_id_location_key on product_stocks pps  (cost=0.41..0.47 rows=2 width=85) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=8)
                    Index Cond: (id_product = "P".id)
                    Filter: ((status)::text <> 'Deleted'::text)
                    Buffers: shared hit=28
        ->  Index Scan using idx_product_files_product on product_files pf  (cost=0.42..0.59 rows=5 width=66) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=5 loops=8)
              Index Cond: (id_product = "P".id)
              Buffers: shared hit=32
  ->  Index Scan using files_pkey on files f  (cost=0.42..0.52 rows=1 width=268) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=40)
        Index Cond: ((name)::text = (pf.img_code)::text)
        Buffers: shared hit=160
Planning Time: 2.581 ms
Execution Time: 350.525 ms
```

Is there an article that explains this behavior to me? and how to fix it?

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL, why tag SQL Server and MySQL as well..?

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS) instead of just EXPLAIN? That will also show us how much time it takes, where most time is spent and if the query planner did a good job

Comment: Did you noticed, that there is no more merge or materialize keywords in the modified query plan? Try to investigate it, why this were present in the first query, but not in the second.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I already edited the question, and added the suggestion  EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS), thanks

Comment: Looks like there is also an issue with work_mem, there is not enough and the data spills to disk:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 102840kB Could you increase work_mem to something like 1GB ? SET work_mem TO '1GB';

Answer (score 2):

That is because [`join_collapse_limit`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html) has a default value of 8. The optimizer tries all permutations only for the first 8 tables, the rest is joined as written. The rationale is to keep planning time reasonably short, which increases exponentially with the number of tables.

Options:

- increase the parameter
- figure out a good join order ans rewrite the query to join in that order